# Overheating and not charging problem when I installed Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, laptop, battery, overheating, charging

After Installing Ubuntu 20.04 I am having an overheating problem and my charging stops because of it even in the idle state of the processors. But with windows neither my charging stops nor my laptop overheats. I was using Ubuntu 19.04 before 20.04 and there wasn't this kind of problem. To avoid this situation I'm using windows, that I don't like. Give me a solution if you have overcome this kind of problem.
I am attaching the system monitors's pic to show you what is the situation of my resources and at this instant, I am facing this problem.

[Here is the image of the system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/960ka.png)

Comment: What is your hardware? I have laptop overheat problem w/ AMD Ryzen 4800H CPU even under stock windows 10!

Comment: @Leder I am using HP 0077tx with intel i5 8th generation processor machine. But I am facing this problem with Windows 10. It is happening with Ubuntu 20.04 OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a constructive discussion with my IIIT Delhi colleagues. I found a solution that is:-

---

Ubuntu 20.04 takes GPU support by default for rendering and other works, So It installs GPU drivers at the installation itself. My computer has NVIDIA GPU which was being used every time. That was the root cause of overheating. So I Opened the NVIDIA driver **NVIDIA X Server** setting and select the **PRIME Profile** option and select the option **NVIDIA On-Demand mode**.

It supports Dynamic switching of NVIDIA GPU when required.

I am Using HP 0077tx machine with i5 8th generation with NVIDIA GPU support. But this is a generic solution for all kinds of machines and GPUs only you have to find the GPU on-demand mode for your GPU and it will work.

Now It reduced Power consumption and eliminate the problem of Overheating and not charging.

---

Upvote this solution if you found the solution helpful so other people can find it easy to overcome their problems too.

Answer (score 1):

I have Dell G3 laptop and NVIDIA graphics card installed in it.
I recently dual booted my laptop with UBUNTU 20.04.1 and while using it, I faced the overheating problem and fast discharge of battery.

To over come this, go change the NVIDIA X Server Settings.
Step 1: Open **NVIDIA X Server Settings**
Step 2: Select **PRIME Profiles**
Step 3: Select **NVIDIA On-Demand**
Note: Using the Intel(PowerSavingMode) didn't resolve the issue.

After changing this settings, please restart the device.
Once you restart the device, you can monitor the temperature in the **NVIDIA X Server Settings**. The temperature shown here will greatly reduce.